# how to get full name of users in template with a ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form look like this:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label="Members",
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'objective', 'duration', 'members']
```

and this is a portion from my template

```
    {% for pk, member in project_form.members.field.widget.choices %}
    <tr>
      <td>

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id_members_{{forloop.counter0}}" value="{{pk}}">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_members_{{forloop.counter0}}">{{member.first_name}}</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I want to get the full name of every user not the username,  how can I do this.

### **Edit**

my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, default='avatars/user.png')

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Comment: Did you try {{ member.get_full_name }} ?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: please, try this:
{% for member in project_form.members %}<tr>
      <td>

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="id_members_{{forloop.counter0}}" value="{{member.pk}}">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="id_members_{{forloop.counter0}}">{{member.get_full_name}}</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

So, now I think I get it. You want to render the form manually so that the full name appears as the label for the checkboxes. To do that, you have to access the queryset attribute of members.

Here is how it would look like,

```
 <form action="" method="post">
     {% for name, field in project_form.fields.items %}
         {% ifequal name 'members' %}

            <div>
                 <label>{{ field.label }}: </label>
                 <ul>
                 {% for member in field.queryset %}
                     <li>
                         <label for="id_members_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                             <input type="checkbox" name="{{ name }}" >
                             {{ member.get_full_name }}
                         </label>
                     </li>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </ul>
            </div>

         {% else %}
             <div>
                <label for="id_{{ name }}">{{field.label}}: </label>
                <input id="id_{{ name }}" type="{{ field.type }}">
             </div>
         {% endifequal %}
     {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

Comment: neither the first nor second approach worked for me, please see my edit above.

Comment: Can you make sure that the Users in Django admin have a first_name and last_name?  It might be the case that both first_name and last_name fields are null.

Comment: the majority of users have first and last name

Comment: Since you have a custom `User` extended from `AbstractBaseUser` you have to include first_name and last_name in your User Model.

Comment: In your templates now it should be `<p> {{member.get_full_name}} </p>`  If this doesn't work, Try accessing the users from a Django shell and confirm that you can actually get their first_name and last_name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174743/discussion-between-oussama-he-and-josewails).

Answer (score -1):

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, default='avatars/user.png')

    def __unicode__(self):
          return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

check it